# Citing Wikipedia with APA 7 and Biber

Tags: biblatex, apa7

I'm trying to cite Wikipedia according to modern APA 7 standards. According to the [Purdue Owl](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/apa_style/apa_formatting_and_style_guide/reference_list_electronic_sources.html) Wikipedia is a special case, by default `biblatex-apa` will reference Wikipedia like this:

> Register Transfer Language. (2021). Wikipedia.

When it should be like this:

> Register Transfer Language. (February 1, 2021). In *Wikipedia*. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Register_transfer_language&oldid=1003495175

A detail that isn't clear by simply looking at the citations is that the date should be the access date, not publishing date.

My bib entry looks like this:

```
@inreference{wiki:rtl,
   title = "{Register Transfer Language}",
   publisher = "Wikipedia",
   year = "2021",
   howpublished = {\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Register\%20transfer\%20language&oldid=1003495175}},
 }
```

And my simple Latex template looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%Packages
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1in, top=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \rhead{Lastname, \thepage}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{xurl} % Better URL management than regular URL.

\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex} % Biber
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color} %red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black, white
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}

% Sans-Serif Font
\newfontface{\headingfont}{Linux Biolinum O}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\headingfont}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\headingfont}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\headingfont}
\addbibresource{refer.bib}

% Master references file. 

% Serif Font
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

% For programming languages.
\lstset{language=C++,%
  basicstyle=\color{red},
  breaklines=true,%
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},%
  morekeywords=[2]{1}, keywordstyle=[2]{\color{black}},
  identifierstyle=\color{black},%
  stringstyle=\color{mylilas},
  commentstyle=\color{mygreen},%
  showstringspaces=false,%without this there will be a symbol in the places where there is a space
  numbers=left,%
  numberstyle={\color{black}},% size of the numbers
  numbersep=9pt, % this defines how far the numbers are from the text
  emph=[1]{for,end,break},emphstyle=[1]\color{red}, %some words to emphasise
  tabsize=4,
  % title=\lstname
}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\newcommand{\teacher}[2]{
\def\theteacher{#1: #2}
}

\newcommand{\myclass}[1]{
\def\theclass{#1}
}

%Title Info
\author{<++>}
\date{\today}
\teacher{<++>}{<++>}
\title{<++>}
\myclass{<++>}

%Renewing commands continued
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
\begin{flushleft}
    \theauthor\\
    \thedate\\
    \theteacher\\
    \theclass\\
\end{flushleft}

\begin{center}
    \bfseries{\thetitle}
  \end{center}
}

%Document
\begin{document}
\doublespace

\maketitle

<++>

\end{document}
```

My LaTeX engine is LuaLaTex and I'm using Biber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`biblatex-apa` has an extensive example `.bib` file which includes many examples from the APA manual. For Wikipedia articles have a look at [the entry `10.3:49` (ll. 1299-1305 in `biblatex-apa-test-references.bib`)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/bd83e1ba023bcc27b115e149b35e1713d8b20033/bibtex/bib/biblatex-apa-test-references.bib#L1299-L1305)

```
% (APA 10.3 Example 49)
@INBOOK{10.3:49,
  TITLE          = {List of Oldest Companies},
  BOOKTITLE      = {Wikipedia},
  URL            = {https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_oldest_companies&oldid=878158136},
  DATE           = {2019-01-13}
}
```

I would only change one thing here: Like you I prefer the type `@inreference` instead of `@inbook`.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inreference{wiki:rtl,
   title     = {Register Transfer Language},
   booktitle = {Wikipedia},
   date      = {2021-01-29},
   url       = {http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Register%20transfer%20language&oldid=1003495175},
 }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,wiki:rtl}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Register transfer language. (2021, January 29). In Wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Register%20transfer%20language&oldid=1003495175]

Comment: This is perfect, did not know about the example .bib file. Thanks a lot.